# Controlling the overflow while displaying inline

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have buttons on either side of an unordered list that overflows. However, I've spent a pretty long time on this, and can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I am aiming to have something like a button on the left, a button on the right, and then the unordered list in between, with the overflow-x hidden and scrollable.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xuak1xek/

HTML/CSS:

```css
button {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline;
}
ul#menu li a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<h2>Horizontal List</h2>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
</ul>  
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the `display` of the `#menu` element to `inline`. In doing so, it will have a ["shrink-to-fit" width](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) and take the size of its children elements. Thus, there is no scrollbar (like you are seeing in your example).

One option would be to set the `display` of the `#menu` element to `inline-block`, and then set a width on it. For instance:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/upt1x5za/)

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu li a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
```

```html
<h2>Horizontal List</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

```
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 400px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

---

You would also use `calc()` to subtract the width of the `button` elements:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mxm74k3e/)

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
}
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu li a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<h2>Horizontal List</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button><!--
--><ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
  </ul><!--
--><button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

```
button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
}
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

---

However, a more *flexible* approach would be to use a flexbox layout and wrap the `#menu` element and buttons with a wrapper. Then you could set the `display` of the `.wrapper` element to `flex.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/bq1x7usL/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu li a {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Horizontal List</h2>
<div class="wrapper">
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="/html/default.asp">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="/css/default.asp">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="/js/default.asp">JavaScript</a></li>
    <li><a href="/php/default.asp">PHP</a></li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your style with this piece it might give you want:

```
ul#menu {
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 45px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

It is setting the ul to display as an inline-block and assigning a specific width. Otherwise it wants to take up the whole width and bumps the buttons above and below it.  If it's not exactly what you want - maybe it'll give you new ideas.

Comment: That exact solution is given already ... so it has to be -1 from me.